# how to run pytest test cases using robot framework?

Tags: python, automation, robotframework, pytest

we have already automated the test cases using feature of pytest, But now we have to use Robot framework for reporting and runnig the test cases. Is it possible to run pytest test cases with robot.

Pytest file: test_sample.py

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.parametrize("test_input,expected", [("3+5", 8), ("2+4", 24), ("6*9", 54)])
def test_eval(test_input, expected):
        print(test_input, expected)
        assert eval(test_input) == expected
```

Executaor file that will be called by robot file.

exec.py

```
import os
import sys

def run_test_cases_of(sample_Test):
    os.system("pytest -s -v test_sample.py" )
```

```
Robot file which is runner: 


 ******settings ***
 Library  test_sample.py
 Library  exec.py


 ****Test Cases ***

 Running test case

    #test eval # When running through this robot is asking for argument
    run test cases of   sample_test #When throygh this robot understaing there is only one test case
```

Comment: No, its not duplicate, I want to run pytest test cases using robot framework.

Comment: You're right, that's no duplicate; however, then it's unclear what you're asking for - you already have given a way of running tests with `pytest` in a subprocess (you can also use `pytest.main(['-s', 'test_sample.py'])` instead - [docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#pytest-main)). What's your question?

Comment: Problems:
1. When calling directly pytest file in robot test case : Robot is not understaing the "@pytest.mark.parametrize" decorator and fails with no arguments found.
2. When running through python sub process : In this pytest triggers three test cases but robot treat this as single test cases and also doesnot logs any details of the actual three test cases, instead it returns os response for this command "pytest -s -v test_sample.py"
.In robot log/report there is entry for single test case that is for keyword "running pytest sample test" which calls test_sample.py

Comment: Robotframework is not meant to run unit tests or any arbitrary code, only text files of custom format. If you want to convert test functions from a python module to robot files, you'll need to write a converter and integrate it as an extension of the framework. Invoking `pytest` for unit tests in a subprocess/via `pytest.main` is the simplest and cheapest solution.

Comment: I tried pytest.main option , it not working.

Comment: Solved this problem by maintaining the tests cases in test suite. If robot test suits are there then using "sanity_gui.robot" and for api "sanity_api.py". Depending on the suite name calling the runner.

Answer (score 0):

It is most logical what you want.

1. Now there is the answer
   https://pypi.org/project/pytest-in-robotframework/.
   This is more like pytest under the hood of the robot framework.
2. You can also check and investigate https://pypi.org/project/pytest_robotframework/
   but it is more like Robot Framework reports in pytest.

In 1) it is exactly used this way `pytest.main(['-s', 'test_sample.py'])`, how it is described in the comments under main post. But is focused on keywords written in Python that have @pytest_execute decorator.

How to use it?
You have to install it

```
pip install pytest-in-robotframework
```

and import

```
from pytest_in_robotframework import pytest_execute

#usage with functions
@pytest_execute
def test_my_function():
    assert  False
```

It means that your example would look like this:

```
import pytest
from pytest_in_robotframework import pytest_execute

@pytest_execute
@pytest.mark.parametrize("test_input,expected", [("3+5", 8), ("2+4", 24), ("6*9", 54)])
def test_eval(test_input, expected):
    print(test_input, expected)
    assert eval(test_input) == expected
```

and when you run the `test_eval` keyword from the Robot Framework test it is executed by Pytest in the background.